# Jquery remove, empty and detach methods are consuming memory

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I've XML contents which contains more then 5000 nodes and I'm removing unneccassary nodes from the xml contents via jquery methods like remove, empty and detach as below. but the problem is performance. it consumes around 65mb as GC and also take half second extra.

`xml.children().not("abc").remove();`

My question is,
Why this is taking too much memory?
and how I can get rid of it.

Comment: To solve, simply don't load unnecessary nodes. If that's not possible, use straight DOM methods, not jQuery. Or use XSLT to transform the original to the new state.

Comment: I'm loading a string file which contain many duplicate nodes as well. and then i'm parsing it into XML content. There is no DOM access. 2ndly, what is the problem with these methods why it is caused this performance issues

Comment: "There is no DOM access"... considering jQuery uses DOM access, there must be. It's likely they're using [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to parse the XML to a DOM document.

Comment: var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(sXML, "application/xml"); , I used this method now for parsing. I find the method removeChild and I've to iterate over the child and if child is not relevent i will remove it. Do you not think it is more expensive method thne jquery empty and remove ? in case of 50k record xml.children().not("abc").remove(); this could be more effecient then dom remove child, Or do you suggest any other method ?

Comment: jQuery is a wrapper around DOM methods. They *cannot* be faster than DOM methods alone. You can see [the source code for `remove`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L218) to see what it's doing, and you'll see a lot of stuff about removing data and event handlers and others. Thus, if you use jQuery, you're getting all of the overhead of jQuery's history as being primarily used for HTML.